# ¿Por qué la URL no cambia en este caso?

Tags: php, api, cache

Enfrento este problema desde hace meses y no entiendo a qué se debe, si es mi navegador, si es servidor, si es algo de caché.

Tengo varias URL que se parecen, son puntos de entrada de una API, por ejemplo:

```
https://deiverbum.org/api/2019/01/tercia/20191002
https://deiverbum.org/api/2019/01/sexta/20191002
https://deiverbum.org/api/2019/01/nona/20191002
```

Si estoy en cualquiera de ella y en la barra de navegación cambio el nombre del punto de entrada no me lo reconoce.

Digamos que estoy en la primera, en `tercia` y voy a la barra de navegación y borro `tercia` y escribo `sexta`, la página no me manda a la segunda URL que muestro más arriba, sino que se queda donde estaba, en `tercia`. A veces tengo que hacer 3, 4, 5, y ¡hasta 7 intentos! para que finalmente me haga el cambio.

Una de las cosas que intenté en el pasado fue forzar la recarga vía `.htaccess` como se sugiere en [esta respuesta](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/105126), pero no obtuve nada.

¿Por qué **a veces** si cambio un punto de entrada no me reconoce el cambio, y tengo que cambiarlo varias veces para que lo reconozca? ¿Por qué a veces hace el cambio a la primera? ¿Qué puedo hacer para siempre haga el cambio a la primera?

Como dato adicional, para que se entienda el contexto, todas estas peticiones son controladas por el archivo `index.php` de la carpeta y el `.htaccess` está así:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

Las cabeceras en uno de esos intentos donde quise pasar de `nona` a `tercia` muestra esto:

Cuando se cargó `nona` correctamente a escribirlo en la barra de navegación:

```
Resumen
URL: https://deiverbum.org/api/2019/01/nona/20191002
Estado: 200
Origen: Red
Dirección: mi.ip:443

Solicitar
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:authority: deiverbum.org
:path: /api/2019/01/nona/20191002
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-es
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Host: deiverbum.org

Responder
:status: 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2019 13:58:33 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.1
x-server-cache: true
x-proxy-cache: HIT
```

Cuando escribí `tercia` en la barra, pero no lo reconoció y se quedó en `nona`:

```
Resumen
URL: https://deiverbum.org/api/2019/01/nona/20191002
Estado: 200
Origen: Red
Dirección: mi.ip:443

Solicitar
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:authority: deiverbum.org
:path: /api/2019/01/nona/20191002
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-es
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Host: deiverbum.org

Responder
:status: 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2019 13:58:40 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.1
x-server-cache: true
x-proxy-cache: HIT
```

Comment: ¿Has revisado lo que te sale en la pestaña network de las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador cuando cambias las URL a mano? (activa preserve log para que no se borre el registro cada vez que cambias). Si alguna vez te llegan respuestas con código 300 o 301 (redireccionamiento) es que es problema del servidor y habría que revisar esa parte. Yo acabo de probar con las URLs que has puesto y no lo he conseguido reproducir con google Chrome, todas las respuestas me dan código 200 (éxito).

Comment: Otra idea, ¿has probado a borrar el historial del navegador? ¿Podría ser que como tienes un historial muy largo con URLs parecidas te esté cambiando en último momento (cuando le das a enter) por otra parecida del historial?

Comment: @ordago gracias por tus sugerencias. Revisa la edición de la pregunta, al final puse la información de un caso donde debió cambiar y no lo hizo. Por otra parte, quisiera no tener que vivir limpiando el historial por esto.

Comment: A la vista de esos resultados, si has escrito tercia y está enviando una request a nona, es que algo está interfiriendo en el navegador desde el momento en que escribes la URL y genera la request. Yo tengo un problema parecido en el proyecto en el que estoy (muchas URLs parecidas que dependen de un id o una fecha), al final en vez de meter las URLs a mano, lo que tengo un html cutre con un formulario que cuando meto un id me hace un GET a la url que necesito con el id. A lo mejor alguien te puede dar una solución mejor.

Comment: @ordago esta es una API que es consumida por una App. Realmente digamos que me conviene ¿? que los datos se guarden en caché para que haya menos carga en el servidor. En la App no hay problema, todo funciona bien, incluso la App tiene varios  módulos (tercia, sexta, nona...) y si cambio de uno a otro me muestra todo bien. Pero como aún estoy alimentando la API con contenido, yo escribo las URL a mano para verificar que una determinada URL tiene el contenido que le corresponde y es ahí donde me encuentro con esta situación y quisiera saber a qué se debe.

Comment: ¿Te ocurre si usas la navegación desde una pestaña de incógnito? Estoy tratando de reproducir tu error y todo me funciona correctamente por lo que me aventuro a afirmar que se trata de un problema con la caché de tu navegador. ¿Cuál usas?

Comment: @phpMyGuel esa prueba también la hice y nada. Lo raro es que si cambio la fecha funciona, o si agrego `?` al final funciona (a veces) o si quito o pongo `/` al final funciona (a veces), pero si cambio el punto de entrada no ¿? Además, se supone que es un cambio de URL, la caché, el navegador, la policía o quien sea no tiene por qué impedírtelo, ¿no? Como navegador uso Safari.

Comment: Desgraciadamente no puedo reproducir el error. ¿Podrías subir un pantallazo de la caja del navegador donde insertas la **URL** antes de darle al *Enter* para lanzarla? Es que si no es un tema del *autocomplete URL* del navegador no sé que podría estar sucediendo. Lo que sí que parece ser es cosa de tu navegador, dado que parece que el resto no podemos reproducir el error.

Comment: @phpMyGuel con la captura de pantalla activada funciona, hice varios intentos para tomar captura de pantalla y siempre cambiaba, en cuanto dejé de activar la captura de pantalla... de nuevo el fallo. Raro, raro, raro.

Comment: ¿Podrías haber estado haciendo algo al respecto con Cookies o Sesiones? Prueba a limpiar el historial de navegación, incluido las cookies y los archivos e imágenes almacenados en caché y prueba a ver si se te sigue reproduciendo el error.

Comment: Si copias la URL al portapapeles, la pegas en un documento, allí la modificas para cambiar "nona" por "tercia", la vuelves a copiar al portapapeles dede ese documento, la pegas en la URL del navegador y pulsas INTRO, ¿te funciona? Porque para mi tiene toda la pinta de ser algún tipo de autocorrector que actúa sobre el campo de texto donde introduces la URL, que "autocorrige" (quizás basándose en la frecuencia con que visitaste cada sitio) según la tecleas

Comment: Me suena que el navegador puede estar almacenando la redirección en caché basándose sólo en el dominio y leí que puede usarlo un máximo de cinco veces para evitar loops. ¿Probaste sacando la parte en la que hace el cambio a https? Si es eso quizás se solucione usando la bandera [R=307] "Temporary Redirect" que obliga al navegador a no usar la url almacenada según lo que entendí.

Comment: Por si alguien tiene un problema similar, la única forma en que puede resolverlo fue haciendo lo que me sugiere @abulafia en [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297848/por-qué-la-url-no-cambia-en-este-caso#comment544725_297848), es decir, escribir la nueva URL en el navegador, luego seleccionar todo, luego copiar, luego pegar, luego enter. Así siempre admite la URL como nueva, discriminando la antigua en todos los casos.

Comment: puedes darle seguimiento a lo que indica la IA [link](https://chat.openai.com/share/42317beb-9243-4ac8-a7a1-03af6488f0cd)